# Short story where a traditional hard-boiled detective who puts himself forward as the last of a dying breed kills the wrong person

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

This is one of those things that popped into my head today and won't exit it, so I'm posting here in hopes that someone might be able to help. I read a short story in the 1990s which featured as a first-person protagonist a hardboiled noir detective who's a bit past his prime in a changing world. He drinks heavily, always helps a dame in trouble, and roughs up suspects in the course of seeking out the truth. A woman comes to him for his aid, and he sets out to use his usual tactics, liberating a set of lead weights from the curtains to weight his punches. I don't remember much of what happens in between, but the story ends with him using those weights while beating up a suspect, and realizing that not only has he killed the man, that the man was completely innocent, and that the rapidly approaching police will now arrest him for murder. I don't remember if it was posed as that he was framed by the women who hired him, or if he just got over-zealous, but the whole thing was definitely supposed to be a deconstruction of the usual film noir manner where the hero investigates with two fists and always turns out to be in the right.

I'm pretty sure that it was part of a book of short detective stories, which might have also included the Gil Hamilton story "[Death by Ecstasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_by_Ecstasy)".